# Realtime Data Visualization Task with LSL

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have to develop a real-time data visualization module in python that is relatively simple, but I don't know where to begin or what tools to use.

Essentially, I would have two images drawn on either side of the screen, and depending on values streamed through lab streaming layer (LSL), the images would change size. That's it.

Any pointers would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Streaming_Data.html, That said, SO seems inappropriate for this kind of help (recommendations and general advice).  You should try the [#python IRC channel on libera.chat](https://www.python.org/community/irc/) next time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help: BrainStreamingLayer. It's a higher-level implementation around pyLSL. https://github.com/bsl-tools/bsl

It has a real-time visualization module, however, the initial use case is EEG amplifiers, so some adaptation may be required.